# Converting Study visa Schengen to Work visa for short period?

Tags: working-visas, student-visa, switzerland

I have a valid study Schengen visa. I stay in EU country. I have finished my studies and I have got an internship for 120 days in Switzerland. Do I need another work visa? If yes, should I be applying in the country where I have stay permit?

If the period is less than 90, will I still need work permit in Swiss (if the previous Schengen is valid)?

Comment: Your question is confusing: What do you have exactly? A student Schengen visa or another type of student visa/permit from a Schengen country (i.e. did your study not last longer than 90 days)? A Schengen visa cannot in any case cover a stay longer than 90 days in total so it sounds unlikely that it's what you have.

Comment: I have student Schengen visa i.e. Type D for long period. But I have finished studies and start working in another EU country (Swiss); that stay is going to be 120 days.

Comment: Please avoid from asking the same question twice. I will answer the other one because it's more specific but one note on the terminology: It's a bit confusing but a type D visa isn't a Schengen visa at all, it's a national visa, with different rules.